# how to add a sequence column based on index?

Tags: r, sequence

I have a dataframe that (simplified) looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to create a third column that creates a sequence from 0 and increment of 50 that begins when the StudioEvent = MovieStart and ends when StudioEvent = MovieEnd. So something like this:

[image]

Any idea how I can do it? Thank you in advance.

I've been asked to attach the code, but honestly, no idea how to even get started which is why I didn't add code in the first place. I thought I'd need to use some type of loop and perhaps mutate function but I wasn't sure. Here's what I initially thought and obviously was wrong.

```
new_data <- data %>%
  group_by(ParticipantName) %>% 
  mutate(Index = StudioEvent$MovieStart == 0)
  ungroup() %>%
```

Comment: Dear @martyna, please post the actual code (not images!), which can be copy-pasted and run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here. If you want a numeric column in a data frame in R, you can't have blank entries like in your example output. They have to be `NA` values. The alternative, depending on your needs, are to have them stored as character strings.

There are probably neater ways to do this, but here is a method in base R using a `for` loop and `if` statements that gets the desired output. Here I'm assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```r
df$sequence   <- numeric(15)
movie_started <- FALSE

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  if(movie_started) df$sequence[i] <- df$sequence[i - 1] + 50
  if(df$Studio.Event[i] == "MovieStart") movie_started <- TRUE
  if(df$Studio.Event[i] == "MovieEnd")   movie_started <- FALSE
}

df$sequence <- as.character(df$sequence)
df$sequence[df$sequence == "0" & df$Studio.Event != "MovieStart"] <- ""

df
#>    index Studio.Event sequence
#> 1      1                      
#> 2      2   MovieStart        0
#> 3      3                    50
#> 4      4                   100
#> 5      5                   150
#> 6      6                   200
#> 7      7     MovieEnd      250
#> 8      8                      
#> 9      9                      
#> 10    10   MovieStart        0
#> 11    11                    50
#> 12    12                   100
#> 13    13                   150
#> 14    14                   200
#> 15    15     MovieEnd      250
```

If you want the `sequence` column in numeric format, you can now do:

```
df$sequence <- as.numeric(df$sequence)
```

---

**Data used**

```
df <- structure(list(index = 1:15, Studio.Event = c("", "MovieStart", 
                "", "", "", "", "MovieEnd", "", "", "MovieStart", "", "", "", 
                "", "MovieEnd")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One follow up question: if I have a data set that's much bigger (say, 191632 observations of 87 variables), how can I adjust the code besides changing: df$sequence   <- numeric(15) to df$sequence   <- numeric(191632)?

Comment: @martyna that should do it. If that's not working then the example in your question must have other differences from those you described.

Comment: thank you once again! Have a good Sunday